# Unable to check state of elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate for my first time a complete flow for a e-comm app. After Add to cart button is clicked, a quantity spinner is displayed instead of that button, with "+" and "-" buttons. I am trying to determine if the button was clicked. If so, click on "-" button and then click again on Add to Cart button for that element and move to next button and so on. This is what I have done so for, but without any luck:

```
private static void addProductsToCart()
{   

    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.className("actions__addToCart")); 
    WebElement action = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/section/ul/div/div/li/div/div/div/div/div/button[1]"));


    for(int i = 0; i <= buttons.size(); i++)
    {
        if(action != null && action.isDisplayed())
           {
               action.click();
           }

        buttons.get(i).click();
        if(i == 4)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="quantitySpinner alignmentContainer__element" data-bind="visible: size().quantity() > 0" style="">
        <button class="decrease" data-bind="click: decrementQuantity, attr: {'aria-label': ogs.gsa.resources.Accessibility_DecreaseQuantity.formatWith({productBrand: model.Brand, productName: model.Name})}" aria-label="Subtract One Birds Eye Steamfresh Chef's Favorites Rotini &amp; Vegetables"></button>
        <label data-bind="text: size().quantity, attr:{'aria-live':'polite', 'aria-atomic':'true'} " aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">1</label>
        <button class="increase" data-bind="click: incrementQuantity, attr: {'aria-label': ogs.gsa.resources.Accessibility_IncreaseQuantity.formatWith({productBrand: model.Brand, productName: model.Name})}" aria-label="Add One Birds Eye Steamfresh Chef's Favorites Rotini &amp; Vegetables"></button>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you share the HTML code ? Why do have a loop for this scenario ? and even why are you coming outta loop if i==4

Comment: I have added the html piece related to those buttons. As for the loop and i==4, it was done that way because I only want to add the first 5 products on each page.

Answer (score 0):

For clicking on decrease button, you can try this code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver , 20);  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.decrease"))).click();
```

As you have mentioned, that you want to click on `click again on Add to Cart button`

for that :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath of add to cart button 
 or any other locator as per your convenience ")))
```

Comment: That would work only if the button add to cart would be clicked for each product. But that's not the case. As the flow goes through pages it can encounter the same products twice. So my goal is to make just a check before add to cart. If "-" is displayed click it, then add that product again to the cart and move to the next check/add to cart.